# Nativescript Tabview Auto Update

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Using Nativescript 5.0 with Angular

The app is using tabview structure.
Each tabview is using component to display data.

What is the best method to update tabs periodically (say every 30 seconds)?

Components are calling api to get realtime data. Initially when App is launched, I am calling api on ngOnInit() of respective component and thus tabs are filled with data.

How do I call these API periodically and from where?

Here is my TabView html file looks like:

```
<TabView id="tabViewContainer">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Batches'}">
        <StackLayout>
            <ns-batches></ns-batches>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>    
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Courses'}">
        <StackLayout>
            <ns-courselist></ns-courselist>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Post'}">
        <StackLayout>
            <ns-postlist></ns-postlist>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Sales'}">
        <StackLayout>
            <ns-sales></ns-sales>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

Comment: Why do you want to update all the tabs periodically , just update the active tab or when user changes the tab.

Comment: I will try your below mentioned solution. Answer to your above question is - I dont want user to wait for API to fetch data on tabchange. API is not hosted on CDN grade server and at the same time end user is having almost no patience to wait for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a selectedIndexChanged event in Tabview and update the data for active Tab
 
`<TabView id="tabViewContainer" (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelectedIndexChanged($event)">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Batches'}">
        <StackLayout>
            <ns-batches (dataYouwanttoUpdate)="updatedInTabViewTs"></ns-batches>`

and in your firsTabItem.ts
`import { Input } from '@angular/core';`
`@Input()
dataYouwanttoUpdate:ObservableArray`

and in your .ts

`onSelectedIndexChanged(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {
        const tabView = <TabView>args.object;
        const selectedTabViewItem = tabView.items[args.newIndex];
switch (args.newIndex) {
            case 0:
//update the ns-batches data.
this.updateData()
...
 default:
                break;
        }
}`

interval: number;

`updateData(){

  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.getdata.getData().subscribe( data => {
      this.batches = data.batches ;
    });
  },500);
}`

Comment: Trying this solution, but cant understand as how updateData from ts file of tabview can update observable data of component which is in separate ts file (in component class)?

Comment: Use @Input from child component. I am also using same strategy for my TabView.

Comment: Updated the answer with sample.